# Download Program to Microcontroller failes "DASWRAPPER::No ECF hardware found"

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, xilinx, infineon

I switched from Mac to Windows and now I'm having problems with connecting to some of my microcontroller boards. (Infineon Aurix Tricore TC275 and Digilent Arty S7).

When I connect the board, it it shown in the device manager, but when I try to flash the project within Aurix Development Studio, it says "DASWRAPPER::No ECF hardware found".

DAS is installed, it also did not discover the board.

I got the same problem with my digilent arty s7 and xilinx vivado suite.

With STM32 Boards and the STM32CubeIDE the download process works.

Is there anybody that got the same issues as me?

I tried Updating Windows, reinstalling DAS and Aurix Development Studio, firewall settings ...

Comment: This question is possibly off-topic since whilst the devices are required for programming, the problem you are having is more likely a Windows OS issue than a programming issue.  Moreover since you have two different boards, it is possible that it is two separate issues.  Either way you should specify _exactly_ what board you are using (preferably with a link), and describe exactly how they are connected to the host - JTAG, serial, USB or whatever?  You really don't want to be asking for people with the same problem - you clearly want people with a solution.

Comment: Does the device appear in Device Manager?